# Package org.springframework.batch.item.excel.* not available

Tags: xml, spring

I am new to Spring Batch. I am trying to read an .xls file using PoiItemReader. But in my jar, package org.springframework.batch.item.excel.* is not available.

**pom.xml**

[image]

```
<dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need the spring batch extention for excel. You find it in github:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel

Comment: Hi , I have included the all dependencies given in pom.xml from github . but still not able to find the item.excel.

Comment: @AbhishekSahu It is not enough it add the dependecies from this pom. you Need the dependency: <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId> 
     <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>      <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>. But it is not available at maven repo

Comment: @Jens-  I have added the complete pom.xml content into my application but still i am  not able to find the batch.item.excel.* package. i did't get what i am  missing here though i completely copy paste the Pom.xml.

Comment: @AbhishekSahu You miss the Project themself!! In the pom there are only the dependencies that are needed by spring-batch-Excel not `spring-batch-excel` themself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EveryOne.

I have taken the all related classes for the excel-reader-extension project and created the jar file and easily used in our existing project without creating any sub Pom.xml

Make sure your jar file should contain the source files else spring will through classNotFound Exception when launching the application.

~Abhishek Sahu

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone spring batch excel project from this link

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel.

and then import it in your IDE and run the mvn clean install command which will automatically make it available in your local maven repository i.e m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Using  spring-batch-excel version 1.0.1 and poi 3.17, It was resolved.

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kumarpankaj18</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>
```